# Problems with formatting menu bar

Tags: html, css, menu, css-float, html-lists

I've made a menu bar using a 'ul' containing 'li', it kept displaying the in reverse order until I added : 
    `.nav-bar .btn{
        float: left;
    }
    .nav-bar ul{
        float: right;
    }`

But after I did that all of the buttons where overlapping and too small. Does anyone know how to fix 
this?

http://jsfiddle.net/w3hp1txq/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed the `<div>` tags inside `<ul>` and added padding. This is an example. You can modify it as per your need or the UI you want.

```css
/*----------nav-bar-----------*/
 .nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
.nav-bar .logo {
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
    height: 90%;
    display: block;
}
.nav-bar .btn {
    width: 21%;
    
    padding-bottom: 1.2%;
   
    float: left;
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #777777;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-bar ul {
    float: right;
}
.nav-bar a {
    
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 12.5%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777777;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <img class="logo" src="logo.png" />
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                  
                        <li class="btn"> 
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                   
                        <li class="btn"> 
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                  
                        <li class="btn"> 
                            <a href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li class="btn selected"> 
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>

                        </li>
                   
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: That fixed it. Is there any way the buttons can be pushed over to the right edge? Like have the 'contact' button be touching the right edge of the screen?